# How to achieve half window in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

How to achieve this kind of window in my android app??
I want to make this kind of window appear on button click. I don't know which view to use for this.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a `BottomSheet` in android. Take a look at this [video](https://youtu.be/a9h8ZfYQA-0) to learn how to Implement a `BottomSheet`.